# Prevent div from overflowing

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a horizontal animated page transition system where the screen scales to accomodate the incoming page. The problem I have is when moving to a smaller page size, the previous (larger) page overflows out of my content wrapper and consequently causes my overall page to extend past the footer. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdfmY.png) screen capture shows my problem.

You can see how the current page exits on the left, after the screen has shrunk to accomodate the incoming smaller page. (the yellow is the footer, the white the unwanted screen extension).

Currently my "page" css is

```
.myPage
{
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

position: absolute;

top: 0;
left: 0;
display:none; /*Pages are displayed once called*/
opacity: 1;
}
```

I've attempted fiddling with overflow-y:hidden which I thought might work but no such luck.

What can I do to keep my page class from extending out of my content and screwing up my page?

EDIT:

Here's the page wrapper.

```
.pageWrapper
{
background: #FF0000;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-perspective: 1200px;
-moz-perspective: 1200px;
perspective: 1200px;
-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Edit2: [A jsfiddle thats broken but features all my code](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesdhooks/5nW2s/1)

Comment: do you want to set height of div according to screen height or something?

Comment: can you show the html of your page?

Comment: Nikhil - My main div is resized based on the height of the incoming page. This causes the previous (larger) page to overflow the now smaller div. I need to crop it but retain the information about its content size, so height:100% was not an option as explored below.

Answer (score 4):

`overflow-y` won't work without a fixed height. Try setting the height to 100% or some other value that looks right.

In this case you could also set `bottom` instead of `height` to give the element a fixed height.

Comment: I played around more and this seems to introduce more problems into my system. Because I resize the screen based on page height, setting the height to 100% makes it so the screen is never resized to the actual content size, but rather the resized dimensions. I tried setting each pages css 'height' property by accessing their .height() property. But overflow doesn't work with this.

Comment: You resize the *screen*?

Comment: I change the height of my main content. My plan is to animate it.  var newHeight = $page.height();
                        $main.height(newHeight);

Comment: Gotcha. I guess you'd need to post some more code to get help with that part. If an element expands to fit its content, overflow is useless.

Comment: There isn't too much more. The main div hierarchy  is 
                <div id="main" class="pageWrapper">
                    <div id="page1" class="myPage">. Then buttons translate the wrapper and resize to the current page. Here's the page wrapper    
.pageWrapper
{
    background: #FF0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
    -moz-perspective: 1200px;
    perspective: 1200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
} nothing to crazy going on. Just need a way to crop the div. Are there any other methods?

Comment: @user2033824 try making a fiddle at jsfiddle.net, you'll get more help (I'll take a look too).

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on jsfiddle (all my files are local), but i've hosted all my code. http://jsfiddle.net/jamesdhooks/5nW2s/1/ Forgive me its not super classy!